# adding js files to Rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a little confused even after going through the [Rails Asset Pipeline tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline). I'm trying to add the latest jquery files. Do I do this through the layout javascript_include_tag or through the application.js ?

If so what is the difference and how would I specify the actual build number if I was using `//= require jquery` in the application.js

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js",
 "jquery.rails.js", 
 "application.js" 
 %>
```

The above method is adding jquery twice once with the above line and then through application.js

```
//= require jquery
```

Is the application require getting the js file from the gem that's installed. In my Gemfile I have the line

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

So my main question is where should I be loading my specific build of jquery from.

Answer (score 2):

`jquery-rails` contains a specific version of jquery (which version will depend on the version of the gem), and that's what is included when you use `//= require jquery`.  If you do this, you should *not* include jquery with `javascript_include_tag`.

If you want to use a different version than the one contained in the `jquery-rails` gem, then set it in the `javascript_include_tag` as you have it and leave out the `//= require jquery` instruction.

To explain a bit further, the `//= require` syntax is used by the asset pipeline to load (and when precompiled, merge into as well) specific files when the `application.js` is loaded.  Among the primary benefits of this are the faster caching and delivery for the single resource file.  Including several scripts separately using `javascript_include_tag` is another way to load the script, but since it adds a separate `<script>` tag for each file, it doesn't get the benefit that is offered by the `//= require` syntax.

For CDN served scripts, however, the lost benefit is mostly made up for.  This is because they are likely already cached by the client, are served very quickly, and are guaranteed not to be modified in the future.

Answer (score 0):

## application.js

files are served (compressed and compiled) in one file in production, meaning:

```
//= require my_file
```

You get:

```
<script ... src="/assets/application.js" ...>
```

containing my_file in application.js, and compressed. This is in a default production configuration:

```
config.assets.compress = true # just to compress
config.assets.compile = false # false to use precompiled assets, you precompile with rake assets:precompile
                              # true to allow compilation in production
```

NOTE: precompile is to convert scss and coffee files to css and javascript and save them under public directory, to not to hit Rails backend when those files are requested.

## javascript_include_tag

```
javascript_include_tag 'application', 'my_second_file'
```

You get:

```
<script ... src="/assets/application.js" ... >
<script ... src="/assets/my_second_file.js" ... >
```

You will have `my_first_file` embedded in application.js if you leave `//= require my_first_file`.

## Where to put

As in production you won't be debugging, will you?, is good to put them in `application.js`.